# I have imported Maven Project from Github to eclipse, inpom.xml dependencies showing underlined in red

Tags: java, xml, selenium, testng, maven-3

When I run project facing an error, in pom.xml file artifact id showing underlined in red

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.addListener(Lorg/testng/ISuiteListener;)V
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your project and then try -

Right click on project -> Click Maven -> update project

Answer (score 0):

Your current `testng` jar is missing `org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.addListener`method. I think your current testng dependency version is lower than **6.5.1** so You have to Update your testng maven dependency to a higher version. You can try with below testng version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am using TestNG version 7.0.1

Comment: Okay. Can you install latest version of testng eclipse plugin